# Throwing validation message to accept input based on ASCII values

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms

I am  newbee  to  C#> Iam  creating  an  app  for  Windows>
iam  creating  windows  forms  in  WPF using  c#. language>

I  have  three  text boxes,three  labels  and  two  buttons  in the  form 1.>

In  one  of  the   textbox, I  have  to  accept  only [ A....Z, a....z &   some  special  characters (&, $)  and  (.,)]>
 I  have  to  Aceept  data  considering  ASCII  codes  of  Input...
For  EX:  ASCII  code  of  A is 65.>
          ASCII  code  of  @ is 64.

If  user  is  typing  any  other  data  other  than  above  mentioned.. i have  to throw  an  validation  message with message  box.>

*MessageBox.show("Please enter Valid  Data");*

I  have  tried some  basic If else  statements,but  it  consuming  more  amount of  memory..

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Instead of  using predefined  regular  expressions                                                          Logic  to  be  implemented  to  accept  Input  considering the  ASCII  codes  of Alphabets,special  characters. @ Microsoft DN.

Comment: Are you using regular expression to check this?

Comment: Iam using  Regular  expression..As  the  amount of Input  to  Validate  is  large.Using  regualr  expression is  not  worthy..do u  have  any alternate  ideas  regarding  this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this if regular expressions are too slow:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string test = "thisIsTheStringToCheck!";

            bool anyInvalidChars = !test.All(isValidChar);

            Console.WriteLine(anyInvalidChars); // Prints True due to the "!" in the string.
        }

        private static bool isValidChar(char ch)
        {
            if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')
                return true;

            if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')
                return true;

            switch (ch)
            {
                case '&':
                case '$':
                case '.':
                case ',':
                // Add more cases as required.
                {
                    return true;
                }

                default:
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, write a simple `CharValidator` class to use like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            CharValidator validator = new CharValidator();

            validator.AddValidAsciiRange('A', 'Z');
            validator.AddValidAsciiRange('a', 'z');
            validator.AddValidAsciiChar('&');
            validator.AddValidAsciiChar('$');
            validator.AddValidAsciiChar('.');
            validator.AddValidAsciiChar(',');

            string test = "thisIsTheStringToCheck!";

            bool anyInvalidChars = !validator.IsValidString(test);

            Console.WriteLine(anyInvalidChars); // Prints True due to the "!" in the string.
        }
    }

    public sealed class CharValidator
    {
        public void AddValidAsciiRange(char start, char end)
        {
            for (char ch = start; ch <= end; ++ch)
                AddValidAsciiChar(ch);
        }

        public void AddValidAsciiChar(char ch)
        {
            if (ch >= 0 && ch <= 127)
                _validAsciiChars[ch] = true;
        }

        public bool IsValidString(string str)
        {
            return str.All(IsValidChar);
        }

        public bool IsValidChar(char ch)
        {
            if (ch < 0 || ch >= 128)
                return false;

            return _validAsciiChars[ch];
        }

        private readonly bool[] _validAsciiChars = new bool[128];
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of  using  normal  characters.                                    I  need  to use  the  ASCII  codes  of  characters to check  the  user  input.  so  that  for  every client requirement changes,we  need  not be  adding  CASE  statement..  @Matthew Watson

Comment: @Kartiikeya You need to specify your requirements more clearly. How will you supply these ascii codes?